# Is there a way to have rails-footnotes gem running on Rails 3 in Linux?

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails-3, sublimetext2

Is there a way to have [**rails-footnotes**](https://github.com/josevalim/rails-footnotes) gem running on **Rails 3** on **SublimeText2** Editor over **Linux**?

It seems like it is only running for MacOS

Thanks in advance,

Santi! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question, and made my own [solution](https://github.com/toch/subl-handler). It's based on [xdg-open](http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0/xdg-open.html). It allows to configure default applications and link them to MIME types. You can then use the command `xdg-open` to open a file or an URI with the correct application.

Those configurations is stored for an user in `$HOME/.local/share/applications/`. Each `.desktop` file sets up an application. When you've added a new one, you need to update the database with [update-desktop-database](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/update-desktop-database.1.html) building/updating the cache database of MIME types handled by desktop files

```
update-desktop-database $HOME/.local/share/applications/
```

And you need to set your application as the default one to handle a MIME type with [xdg-mime](http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0/xdg-mime.html)

```
xdg-mime default <your desktop file> <your MIME type>
```

The MIME type handling a URI starts with `x-scheme-handler/<your scheme>`. For instance, `x-scheme-handler/subl` for any URI starting with `subl://`.

Chrome and Firefox browsers will use the default applications when browsing that kind of URI.

You'll find the details in that [Bash script](https://github.com/toch/subl-handler/blob/master/install.sh) setting up that for Sublime Text.